# Sencha Touch Anchored Popup Window with Buttons

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to create an anchored popup window containing buttons which when clicked a new view is created. Please refer to screenshot below (taken from the yelp mobile app). I have not been able to find examples of this functionality - thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't knw how to create an anchored popup window but you can try implementing [Action Sheet](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ActionSheet) in Sencha Touch-2.
 It is not anchored but it can contains buttons on which you can provide functionality.

Comment: Action Sheet looks promising but this is for a tablet app where docked at the bottom of the screen is less desirable in terms of ui

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138899/sencha-touch-using-actionsheet

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is really just a floating panel.

See for instance the [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel) and their example using the [showBy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-showBy) method.

Hope that this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
This issue can be resolve by calling a panel inside a container.
```

//Add container1.js in view

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.container1', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.container1',
xtype: 'container1',
//fullscreen: true,

config: {
scrollable: true,
height: 50,
     items: [
         {
              docked: 'top',
              xtype: 'titlebar',
              items: [
              {
              xtype: 'button',
              ui: 'confirm',
              text: 'Back',
              itemId: 'button113',
              id: 'rightButton',
              handler: function () {
              var sh = Ext.create('Sencha.view.panel1', {
                                    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
                                    fullscreen:true,

                                });
                                sh.show();


              }
              }
              ]
          }
     ]
     }
 });
```

//Add panel1.js also in View

```
Ext.define("Sencha.view.panel1", {
extend: "Ext.Panel",
alias: "widget.panel1",

config: {


        html: 'Floating Panel',
        //left: 0,
        //padding: 50,
        items: [
        {   
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Edit Bussiness',

        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Add Photo',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Add BookMark',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Check In',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Write Review',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Make Reservation',
        },

            {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            height: 20,
            text: 'Cancel',
                handler: function() { 
                this.up('panel').hide();
                }
            },

        ],
        listeners: [
        {  hide: { fn: function(){ this.destroy();} }},


       ]
}
});
```

//App.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    controllers: ['Main'],

    views: ['container1', 'panel1'], //add all the view files here which you wants to call on any other panel so that the instance of it will be created.
    stores: [],
    models: [],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container1'
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]
This work for me and will give you the same output. Moreover, on cancel Button it will hide the panel Hope this will help you.
Thanks